# Eclipse General Project alternative in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, pycharm

Within Eclipse IDE I can import any folder as General project.
It is super quick to open (no any builders/compilers), and I can start browsing editing file before or during compilation from command line, as some project may require a lot of time for initial setup due to many dependencies need to download from Internet.

it just creates one `.project` file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>projectname</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Question: How can I open a folder as project in IntelliJ IDEA or any other Jetbrains IDEs?
(Without configuring what kind of builder is used, etc)

Comment: Have you tried File | Open... in 2019.3.4 IntelliJ IDEA version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andrey pointed,

File | Open.. and selecting any folder does the same.

(And creates `.idea` subfolder.)